# The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/wsHttpBinding does not have a configured binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, wshttpbinding, wcf-wshttpbinding

I'm trying to create a second endpoint in my WCF web service. I can bring up the new endpoint's "Happy Page" by putting the domain URL in my browser, so I know that IIS can find the service, using my user account, properly.

However, if I try to run the web page that calls the service, I'm getting the error below

```
The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/wsHttpBinding does not have a configured 
binding named 'WSHttpBinding_IMonetToDss'. This is an invalid value for 
bindingConfiguration. (D:\webcontent\Monet\web.config line 178).
```

Since this section of the config file is auto-generated by Visual Studio when I create the service reference the `bindingConfiguration` value is `WSHttpBinding_IMonetToDss`.. which it's saying it shouldn't be.

Below are both enpoints pulled from the web.config. The first endpoint `/OKeeffe/OKeeffe.svc` is working properly. The second endpoint for `/OKeeffe/MonetToDss.svc` is having the issue.

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://insidesoap.dev.symetra.com/Escher/EscherService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IEscherService"
    contract="Escher.IEscherService" name="WSHttpBinding_IEscherService" />
  <endpoint address="http://insideapps.dev.symetra.com/OKeeffe/OKeeffe.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAgentPayments"
    contract="AgentPayments.IAgentPayments" name="WSHttpBinding_IAgentPayments">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="s.AgentData.dev" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="http://insideapps.dev.symetra.com/OKeeffe/MonetToDss.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMonetToDss"
    contract="MonetToDss.IMonetToDss" name="WSHttpBinding_IMonetToDss">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="s.AgentData.dev" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

**EDIT**

Here's the `system.serviceModel` section of the web service config file

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="OKeeffeDataService.MonetToDss"
            behaviorConfiguration="MonetToDssBehaviors" >
        <endpoint address=""
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            contract="OKeeffeDataService.IMonetToDss" />
        </service>
        <service name="OKeeffeDataService.AgentPayments"
               behaviorConfiguration="OKeeffeBehavior" >
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="OKeeffeDataService.IAgentPayments" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="OKeeffeBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="MonetToDssBehaviors" >
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors> 
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

are you sure you have defined a binding named "WSHttpBinding_IMonetToDss" in your config file? something like this...

```
<bindings>
<wsHttpBinding name="WSHttpBinding_IMonetToDss">
...
</wsHttpBinding>    
<bindings>
```

Comment: Do you mean in the web site or the web service itself? Just posted a section of the config from the service.

Comment: @NealR - It needs to be defined in the `<system.serviceModel>` section of the config file that with the endpoint(s) that reference it(them).

Comment: I believe that's what I've done: `<service name="OKeeffeDataService.MonetToDss"
            behaviorConfiguration="MonetToDssBehaviors" >
        <endpoint address=""
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            contract="OKeeffeDataService.IMonetToDss" />`

Comment: I was asking... is there any "<bindings>" section in your config? It should be there with <wsHttpBinding name="WSHttpBinding_IMonetToDss">. It is not there in your config. so add it. pls refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733099(v=vs.110).aspx. check the last example

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is the solution, I did not copy this part into my env configs for deployment